# How to get value of second element from list in tcl?

Tags: tcl

i have tcl list

```
data =  {{"a" "1"} {"b" "2"}} {x y}}
```

now when am doing -

```
set str [lindex $data 1]
```

am getting values-

```
x y
```

How i can get values 1 2 ?

i tried using

```
set str [lindex $data 2]
```

but am getting null values?

Comment: What is `data`?

Comment: data is tcl list @RenaudPacalet

Comment: So, please show how you assign it.

Comment: Your assignment of `data` is not valid tcl syntax (`=` sign instead of set, too many closing braces). Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

If you have:

```
set data {{{"a" "1"} {"b" "2"}} {x y}}
```

Then you can extract `1 2` with:

```
set extracted [lmap pair [lindex $data 0] {lindex $pair 1}]
```

This is a bit messy because we want to extract a sublist to process and then do an element extraction for each element of that sublist; hence the two `lindex` calls and the `lmap`.

---

If the data had instead been:

```
set data {{"a" "1"} {"b" "2"} {x y}}
```

Then we'd be looking at perhaps:

```
set extracted [lmap pair [lrange $data 0 end-1] {lindex $pair 1}]
```

The main idea is still `lmap` and `lindex`, but we do a range selection first. These techniques combine; it really depends on the data (and it is often better to try to ensure things aren't so complicated in the first place, if possible).

---

If you had:

```
set data {{"a" "1"} {"b" "2"} {"c" "3"}}
```

Then the extraction is the simplest case:

```
set extracted [lmap pair $data {lindex $pair 1}]
```

Comment: SO should have a "number of users writing an answer to post at this very moment"-gauge. (Discards draft.)

Comment: I'm far more bothered by what happens when the questioner deletes their question while I'm half-way through writing an answer…